# Double normalization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix of full rank. Are there diagonal positive definite matrices $X\in {m\times m}$, $Y\in R^{n\times n}$, such that all the rows of $XAY$ have identical norms, and the columns of $XAY$ also have identical norms, not necessarily equal to the norms of the rows?

Comment: This isn't always possible. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}$ for instance.